# How can I setup a bare GIT repository that after pushes the new content is visible?

Tags: git, repository, collaboration, configuration-management, git-bare

I have this scenario: A colleague of mine and I are working on the same branch (master) of a git project "xy". In order to make teamwork possible, i created a bare repository of the project and put it on a network drive which is accesible to both of us. Now we both are pushing and merging new files and folders to the bare repository.

My boss however wants to see the progress, unfortunately this isn't possible unless he clones the repository. What would be really nice was for my boss and other members of the group if they could look into the files, open them and so on. Something like Github would be great. If I push items to a (bare) Github repository I can browse online through the changes.

Any ideas on how to improve the setup are highly appreciated.

Comment: 'git --git-dir=BARE_REPOS git show FILEA'   can show the files if he just wants to see them.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use github to do what you want.  A nice alternative to github is GitLab, which has a free, open-source community edition that you can host locally if you don't want your repositories living in the cloud.

For a more bare-bones alternative, you can add a post-receive hook to your bare repository that does an export to the directory of your choice whenever a developer pushes to it.  Then your boss can examine the pushed code in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

In a protected environment, install lighttpd and perl-cgi, then use `git instaweb`. ([Its docs](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb))